# Como reducir sentencias if en java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, condiciones

Buenos dias programadores,

Estoy intentando reducir las siguientes sentencias if para ahorrar lineas inecesarias de codigo.

```java
        // Si el campo email no esta vacio imprime el color azul, sino el rojo
        if(input_Email.getText().length() > 1) {
            input_Email.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_blue)));
        }else{
            input_Email.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_red)));
        }
        if(input_Pass.getText().length() > 1) {
            input_Pass.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_blue)));
        }else{
            input_Pass.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_red)));
        }
```

Lo que estaba pensando era hacer un for para realizar esto, algo como lo siguiente:

```java
        String[ ] inputs = {"input_Email","input_Pass"};

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            if(inputs[x].getText().length() > 1) {
                inputs[x].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_blue)));
            }else{
                inputs[x].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_red)));
            }
        }
```

Esto no funciona ya que estoy llamando a una string con inputs[x] y no al componente EditText de android studio.

Mi consulta es, se puede reducir esas sentencias if?

Agradezco las respuestas constructivas!

Comment: Buenas! Solo una curiosidad ¿Tiene sentido utilizar el mismo validador para el mail y para la password? Yo haría dos funciones validateMail y validatePassword (que tenga más de n caracteres, números, símbolos, etc etc). Luego, puedes devolver una lista de los campos con error y ahí sí usar el loop para pintar rojo o azul :)

Comment: Comprendo tu sugerencia, el punto es que queria lograr un Frontend definido para continuar posteriormente con las funcionabilidades de la app. Es importante como tu dices validar esos campos antes de hacer una consulta, Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de dar con la respuesta

```java
        // Cambie String por EditText
        EditText[ ] inputs = {input_Email,input_Pass};

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            if(inputs[x].getText().length() > 1) {
                inputs[x].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_blue)));
            }else{
                inputs[x].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.g_red)));
            }
        }
```

Dejo la publicación por si a alguien en un futuro tiene el mismo inconveniente

Comment: Si ya respondiste a tu pregunta puedes seleccionarla como respuesta.